# Connect Google Double Click Manager with Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, double-click-advertising

I was wondering if it is possible to connect [Google Doubleclick Campaign Manager (DCM) API](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/) to [Jira](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) to trigger the creation of an issue.

Comment: What would be the point? Please explain the workflow you want to implement. What action would fire a request to JIRA to create an issue?

Comment: I did my best to improve your question, but we need some code demonstrating an attempt to solve it for this to be useful on StackOverflow.